# Disabling download dialog box

Tags: php, firefox, download

Is there any way to disable the download dialog box in Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.. using php?

Because I have a project, its like a file management, where the users (client) will just view the files (.doc, .ppt, .pdf, etc) and they should not be able to download it.

For me, I think it cannot be.. But to you guys I know you have ideas on how to do it. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated..

Comment: what do you mean by "view the files".. view the directory structure and the fact that the files exist or view the contents of the files? if the file management needs to show a directory you don't need to link to them directly.. just scan the directory and show the output

Comment: @mishu, viewing of the files... the files are uploaded to a database, and how can I show the output???

Comment: I meant showing the output of a directory scan.. but it seems that this is not the case.. if you show the files to a user I don't think you can prevent him from saving the file.. opening or downloading the file is a choice that the browser makes depending on what it is able to read

Comment: yeah your right... it's the browsers behavior.. but do you think is there any way to solve this?? it brings me no hope to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MS Office itself to convert all my docs to .html extension.. then I upload it to my intranet site.. so my members can only view the information I uploaded.. I used some javascript to disable the right click button so no one can save that file.

Comment: Restricting content like that is trivial to bypass. As long as it is online, and the user can 'see' the link to the document, they will be able to get at the file.

Comment: No.. It is in my database already. The users cannot see the link of my document. So thay cannot download the file.

Comment: I think there may be a miscommunication here, see hakre's answer for a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> they should not be able to download it

It does not depend how a browser offers a user-interface for a resource located at an internet-address (URL or URI): Dialog box or view-port - **the file is always downloaded**.

So the answer is **no** because a user is always able to download it - as the browser must be able to do so.

Comment: @Kevzz: Next to that, the type of user-interface offered is configured by the user within it's browser and operating system. You can try to influence that, but it's not strict nor safe, would be only guessing and it does not prevent anything.